# How can I prevent hinged mirrors from swinging out of position?

Tags: mirror, ikea

I’ve purchased the Tonal exercise machine and saw someone in the online community post photos of how they installed two full length mirrors on each side (the IKEA Nissedal). The mirrors come with hinges that allow the mirrors to swivel, but those hinges have no resistance to them so the mirrors automatically want to freely swivel to their own stopping point. I’d like to make them stay in place once I’ve set the desired angle. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure of those hinges/pivot points, but there are quite a few that have resistance settings.  Either a screw/nut that tightens a spring or rubber that holds against turning.  If you add a picture of those hinges someone might have an idea.

Comment: @crip659 Thank you for the reply. I've added a couple of photos in case it might help.

Comment: They look like just plain cabinet/cupboard hinges.  Should be able to replace them with hinges that have resistance built in.  Any hardware store should be able to match them with ones that will hold in place.

Comment: @BradG do the mirrors want to swing freely to the wall, or away from it?

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the hinges with hinges designed for this application - the side mirrors on 3-way mirror furniture may have "teeth" between the barrels to hold them at small increments, based on some examples I'm familiar with.

You could least expensively remove the hinges and drop them in salt water for a bit to rust enough that they don't move freely anymore.

You could use a center punch to deform the hinge barrels until they bind a bit on the shaft.

You could jam the bottoms in place with foam blocks, books, or flexible sticks cut just a bit longer than the distance to the floor and bent into position.

You could attach a stick or rod to the wall with a clamp to hold the mirror to it at the desired position.

You could set a shelf on top of the two mirrors. Don't use it to hold heavy items.

Answer (score 0):

If they're moving it's because either your wall is out of plumb your your hinges are. If the pins are vertically coaxial they won't move. I'd start there. Either shift a hinge sideways as needed or shim one of them out.

Granted, even with vertically-aligned hinges a light breeze would move the mirrors, but this solves the primary problem.

Comment: Or mount stays, or catches, or magnets to hold them at the desired position. Or reconsider the hinge mounting and make them floor-standing. Or....